# Fast text search in Rust

Tags: performance, strings, multithreading, rust, search

I have a large file that I want to search for text as fast as possible. There is not a memory contraint, so I am loading the entire file into memory so that I can use the rayon parallelism crate in order to improve performance (so I don't get blocked by an IO thread). I have the following code (I've indented the benchmark lines to stand out from the functional code):

```
extern crate rayon;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let now = Instant::now();

    let mut f = File::open("words_huge.txt")?;
        let time_to_open = now.elapsed().as_millis();

    let mut whole_file = String::new();

    let n = f.read_to_string(&mut whole_file)?;
        let time_to_read = now.elapsed().as_millis() - time_to_open;

    let mut lines = whole_file.par_lines(); // Split it into lines
        let time_to_line_split = now.elapsed().as_millis() - time_to_read;

    let mut results: Vec<&str> = lines.filter(|l| l.contains("test")).collect();
        let time_to_process = now.elapsed().as_millis() - time_to_line_split;

    for r in results
    {
        println!("{}", r);
    }

    let time_to_print = now.elapsed().as_millis() - time_to_process;
    println!("Time to open: {}", time_to_open);
    println!("Time to read: {}", time_to_read);
    println!("Time to line split: {}", time_to_line_split);
    println!("Time to process: {}", time_to_process);
    println!("Time to print: {}", time_to_print);
    println!("Total time elapsed: {}", now.elapsed().as_millis());
    Ok(())
}
```

Please provide feedback on how this could be further optimized. Could I be performing fewer memory operations in the name of speed? Is there too much overhead to threading here? Note that words_huge.txt is a text file with over 10 million lines of text from the English dictionary repeated over about 20 times.

Note: This is going to be machine and even run-dependent, but the current version above does execute quite fast... processing time takes 172-185ms on my machine... Pretty good for 10 million lines! But can we do better?

Comment: You are processing 10 million lines faster then the human reaction time. Come back and ask for optimization help when you have task that you actually have to wait for.